# Invisible DVD/CDROM drive

Tags: drivers

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 on my Toshiba Satellite A75-S206 but my DVD/CDROM is not showing. As a result, I'm unable to install "Precise Pangolin". How can I reinstall my driver?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the CD?  If so, how did you get it?  If you burned it, then it must be recognized.

Assuming you have the CD, is the problem that it won't boot from the CD?  If so, this isn't a driver issue, since no operating system is even present at boot time, and a driver is part of the operating system.  The problem would be that your BIOS is not set to boot from the CD, which isn't really a Ubuntu problem.  But the solution is to press the key that brings up the BIOS before booting (often either delete or F1, but it should tell you briefly when you restart), and tell it to boot from the CD before the hard disk drive.